# Does schemacrawler supports Hive?

Tags: hive, visualization, schemacrawler

I am looking for data visualization tool which supports Hive database.

Does schemacrawler supports Hive? If not, any roadmap to support it in future.

Any other tools which support Hive to view its metadata?

Let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the SchemaCrawler [Database System Support](http://www.schemacrawler.com/database-support.html), which states that SchemaCrawler supports any database that has a JDBC driver. It seems that Hive has a [JDBC driver](https://www.cloudera.com/downloads/connectors/hive/jdbc/2-5-4.html), so you can try it out.